# Aptana function definition popups

Tags: aptana

I've noticed that in Aptana 2.0 over 1.5.1 that when typing a php function, you no longer get the popup window showing the function description and it's parameters.

Does anyone know how to get this working again? As I relied on it quite heavily to remember which parameters went where. `Open in PHP Manual` shortcut `Shift+F2` also doesn't work either, so all I can do is open my browser and keep php.net open all the time.

Are either of these features functional? I know that `Open delcaration` has never worked annoyingly, but I had the function popup in 1.5.1 perfectly.

Comment: The php plugin in Aptana is discontinued, so you can't expect it to be working reliably. To get reliable php support in Eclipse, use PDT.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Aptana 2.0.4 and PDT 2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

I use this [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to get the PHP manual in a new browser tab for the selected text in any program:

```
;Windows+p for Google's I'm feeling lucky "php + selected text"
#p::
oCB := ClipboardAll ; old Clipboard
Sendinput, ^c
GoogleSearch:= "http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=php+" Clipboard
ClipBoard := oCB ; restore ClipBoard
Run, %GoogleSearch%
return
```

Not ideal, but will get you the PHP manual quickly.

Comment: Definitely a great workaround, but still not quite as slick as having the info in the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

First, go to `Window -> Open Perspective -> Other` and check you're in the PHP perspective and not the Aptana Web one. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it can't hurt to try.

Secondly, try right clicking on a PHP file in Aptana's navigator / project explorer and go to `Open With -> (Other ->) -> PHP Editor`. This will open it with PDT, instead of Aptana's web editor (which has discontinued PHP support).

Comment: Great suggestions! I've given it a try in the PHP Perspective with no luck, and my default editor for PHP files is 'PHP Editor' so I guess I'm in that already! Still no luck mind