# Cannot find code completion and suggestions in Aptana 2.0

Tags: aptana, code-completion

I recently started using Aptana 1.5 to work on a site via FTP, developing pages in .php format with a mixture of HTML, CSS, jQuery, and -- naturally -- PHP. I develop a page with all of these elements together to save time, then separate them.

One thing that I really liked about Aptana 1.5 was that it completed code (brackets, parentheses, etc) and suggested things as I typed. I upgraded to 2.0 today and cannot figure out for the life of me how to bring back all of these capabilities -- or remember if I had to do anything in 1.5 to get them. Here is a picture of what I am looking for
[image]
<sub>(source: [tapp-essexvfd.org](http://tapp-essexvfd.org/images/grab.jpg))</sub>

Notice the suggestion for margin: and the "HTML, Js, CSS" up top.

Any help with getting this to work in 2.0 would be greatly appreciated. Ever since installing 2.0, 1.5 has been throwing error messages and I can't seem to get my FTP settings to stay locked in.

Comment: Yeah, this is the same as my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644056/aptana-function-definition-popups

Answer (score 0):

My Aptana doesn't have the "HTML, JS, CSS" up top when editing PHP files. Make sure you've got [PDT installed](http://www.aptana.org/php).

First, go to `Window -> Open Perspective -> Other` and check you're in the PHP perspective and not the Aptana Web one. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it can't hurt to try.

Secondly, try right clicking on a PHP file in Aptana's navigator / project explorer and go to `Open With -> (Other ->) -> PHP Editor`. This will open it with PDT, instead of Aptana's web editor (which has discontinued PHP support).

Answer (score 0):

For Studio 2, you would need to install PDT on top of it.  However, I would recommend using Studio 3 as it has PHP support built in.